# Expected Value of Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is assignment question so I don't need an answer but just a hint. How do you find out expected number of certain values that are less than or greater than certain number. We've only covered E(X) = lambda formula. We haven't covered anything like E(X<#) or E(X>#). Is there such formula?

Comment: If you mean something like $E(X<6)$, then I wonder if you mean $P(X<6)$, and if not, then I don't know what you have in mind.

Comment: The question asked for "the expected number of values which are < 18." All I know is how to find expected value of distribution that doesn't have constraint like this one.

Comment: If you observe the value of a Poisson-distibuted random variable, you observe _one_ value.  So my guess is you mean you have an i.i.d. sequence of Poisson-distibuted random variables, rather than just one.

Comment: The mean is given(17) and there are 300,000 values and the question ask to find "expected # of values among 300,000 which are < 18"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm going to go with the guess I made in the comments.  Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables, each with a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda$, and what you want is the expected number of these that are less than some particular number $x_0$.  Then you have $p=P(X_1 < x_0) = \sum\limits_{0\le x<x_0} P(X=x)$.  That's the probability of "success" on one trial.  So you want the expected number of successes in $n$ trials, with probability $p$ of success on each trial.  That's just $np$.  The number of successes in $n$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success on each trial is a random variable with a binomial distribution, so the expected value of such a random variable is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks that what I was looking for.